# Issue with importing instance in ReactJS. Can someone explain me why this works?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, axios

I have this module ([src/api/axios.js](https://github.com/sickdyd/booking-manager/blob/master/frontend/src/api/axios.js)) that exports an instance of `Axios` with custom `baseURL` and a `header`. I set in the header the token I retrieve with `authenticate.getToken()`:

```
import Axios from "axios";
import authenticate from "../classes/Authenticate";

const axios = Axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:3333/api",
    headers: { "x-auth-token": authenticate.getToken() },
});

axios.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json";

axios.interceptors.request.use(request => {
  console.log(request);
  return request;
}, error => {
  console.log(error);
  return Promise.reject(error);
});

axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
  console.log(response);
  return response;
}, error => {
  console.log(error);
  return Promise.reject(error);
});

export default axios;
```

I import `axios.js` in another module ([src/api/client.js](https://github.com/sickdyd/booking-manager/blob/master/frontend/src/api/client.js)) where I handle requests:

```
import axios from "../api/axios";

export default {
  // User
  login(email, password) {
    return axios.post("/authenticate/", { email, password });
  },

  // Schedule
  getSchedule() {
    return axios.get("/schedule/");
  }
}
```

**THE PROBLEM**

If I import `axios.js` **ONLY** in `client.js`, I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getToken' of undefined

It seems that the instance of `Authenticated` is undefined.

**THE FIX THAT I DON'T UNDERSTAND**

However, if I import `axios.js` in `App.js` AND in `client.js` it works. Why? The import of `axios.js` I have in `App.js` is not being used.

You can check out the repo here:

https://github.com/sickdyd/booking-manager/tree/master/frontend

Comment: I bet you have a cycle in your import graph which is broken by importing `axios.js` in such a way as to break that cycle. I'm on a phone or else I'd look into it more deeply but try not to have module A import module B which imports module C which imports module A which... etc

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that and see if I can fix it!